# How to remove the Type 3 error from Pdflatex?

Tags: formatting, font-encodings

I finished preparing a book in latex (Texmaker). When I submitted the pdf file to the press, they showed type 3 font error:

> Font F44, F45 is a Type 3 font (239x on pages 16...337)

I don't understand the error. Following is my latex preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,openany,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in, top=1.93cm, bottom=1.93cm, bindingoffset=0.36cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{}{0pt}{\huge}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries\centering}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries\flushleft}{}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{text-angstrom={Å},math-angstrom={\text{Å}}}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\RNum}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}
\newcommand{\rnum}[1]{\lowercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }
\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.89cm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.89cm}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
```

Could somebody tell me what went wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Id guess it is the esint fonts, hard to tell from the fragment you have posted

Comment: note that it's not an error just a policy issue, a type3 font is a postscript font typically made from a metafont bitmap font, they presumably only want to see type1 (scalable) fonts.

Comment: the pdffonts utitility or the font menu in your pdf reader should show the fonts used and their types

Comment: Yes. I understand that its not an error. When I opened it in Adobe and searched for the fonts, it shows 2 fonts F44 and F45 that belongs to the Type 3 encoding.

Comment: hmm that's the internal font number usually you get a hint of the original name, do you load any fonts other than lmodern and esint? (or include eps files or pdf files)

Comment: You were correct. It was the esint package. Thank you so much.

Comment: One more thing. Can I use the times pakage along with the T1 font encode?

Comment: Something is wrong with your setup I get type 1 version of the esint fonts in texlive2020 from `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,esint}

\begin{document}


\[\int_0^1 x dx\]

\end{document}`

Comment: `ZJYOPT+esint10                       Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       4  0`

Comment: you could use times but I wouldn't recommend it these days if you want a times like look use `newtxtext,newtxmath` instead of lmodern.  note the T1 in the fontenc option is unrelated to the type1 font format